# SQL 2008 R2 Clustering AND DB Mirroring (Async)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, failovercluster, database-mirroring

I've got a MS SQL 2008 R2 Fail-Over Clustered Instance running between two Windows 2008 R2 servers using the inbuilt Windows Clustering features, that is working with a DTC and Quorum with a disk based Witness. This has been working fine for months and little concerns with the functionality.

I've now been asked to add DB Mirroring to an alternate site (asynchronously) but when setting up the Mirroring partners the Endpoint on the cluster fails to respond. Pinging the Cluster Name returns the clusters IP so I'm not sure how to confirm its routing to the active host.

Firewall port has been opened on both the remote server and the two clustered servers.

Can anyone direct me on the steps you need to take to do Asynchronous database mirroring on a W2008R2/MSSQL2008R2 Fail-Over Cluster in order to make the Endpoint on the cluster reachable by the mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the wasted time, I didn't realise at the time but when I restored the database to the second server I didn't select restore with NO RECOVERY. After making the change and attempting to mirror again the process worked.

I still don't understand why I was receiving an error indicating the cluster was not responding considering the problem was on the stand-alone mirrored server.

Comment: What was the error message you received on the mirror server when trying to connect? These would likely be in the SQL Server error logs on the mirror server.